# Update the DependencyGraph programmatically in Jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I would like to update the DependencyGraph in Jenkins.

Some part of the code:

```
 def pl = z.getPublishersList()
            for(w in pl){
                       def bt = w.grep(hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger.class) 

          println(bt )
          for(aa in bt){
            println("BT " + aa.getChildProjectsValue())

                 pl.add( new hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger("TestTop2", false)) 
}
}
```

I try to use

```
  def newtop =  hi.getItem("TestTop2")
def  graph3 = Hudson.getInstance().getDependencyGraph()
newtop.buildDependencyGraph(graph2)
```

But that doesn't work. Whats the correct way to rebuild the DependencyGraph ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will rebuild the DependencyGraph from the script console

```
def hi = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
hi.rebuildDependencyGraph()
```